# Manipulação de configurações de Rede em Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, redes

Trabalho em ambiente linux, Python 2.7, e estou precisando de um módulo/biblioteca em Python que me permita alterar as configurações de rede (IP, Subnet, Gateway e, se possível, DNS primário e secundário).

Verifiquei algumas bibliotecas (`netaddr`, `ipaddress`, `netifaces`, `IPy`), mas elas só me permitiram ler e fazer verificações com os dados da placa de rede (consegui extrair estas informações e mostrar na tela), mas nenhuma me permite fazer alterações nessas informações.

Meu software deverá permitir que o usuário tenha a opção de deixar o IP estático na máquina, e para rodar a `os.system("")` para alterar via terminal, eu precisaria estar logado como root.

Se alguém souber alguma maneira de fazer este tipo de alteração, ficarei eternamente agradecido.

Comment: Posso estar enganado, mas acredito que mesmo que você encontre uma biblioteca que faça isso você ainda vai precisar estar logado como root, uma vez que fará uma alteração no sistema.

Comment: Está certo. Porém queria manipular estas informações de dentro do Python, mas pelo jeito vou ter que chamar a biblioteca 'os' mesmo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

acredito que `pyroute2` seja suficiente para atender suas necessidades, já brinquei com ela uma vez, é uma biblioteca bem completa, da pra adicionar **routes**, criar **vlans** e diversos outros, o script precisa ser executado como **root** sim, já que essas alterações exigem privilégios administrativos. no site do **Pypi** tem alguns exemplos:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyroute2

segue um exemplo:

```
from pyroute2 import IPRoute
ip = IPRoute()

idx = ip.link_lookup(ifname='enp1s0')[0]

ip.link('set',
        index=idx,
        state='up')


ip.addr('add',
        index=idx,
        address='10.0.0.1',
        broadcast='10.0.0.255',
        prefixlen=24)

ip.close()
```

Comment: Legal - eu achei a Pyroute também - acho que é o caminho certo.  (Aí fiquei escrevnedo dicas erais de Python, em vez de dar um exemplo com pyroute)  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Acho que essa [pyroute2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyroute2/0.4.12) faz o que você está pedindo.

Se não der certo, e você conseguir identificar comandos do shell que façam a configuração que você precisa, usar o Python para rodar esses comandos pode ser melhor do que, por exemplo, tentar modificar os arquivos de configuração diretamente do Python (vai dar menos trabalho e e se você  errar e gerar um arquivo sintaticamente errado nas configurações do sistema vai dar bem mais trabalho do que se o Python simplesmente emitir um comando inválido)

A dica que fica é, em vez de usar o `os.system`, usar a biblioteca [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) do Python  - por que ele permite bem mais controle do processo externo, se você quiser por exemplo, ler o que o programa externo imprime na saída padrão e usar esses valores no Python.

E por fim, mas não menos importante - use Python 3 - qualquer que seja sua distribuição Linux, ela vai permitir instalr o Python3 em paralelo ao Python2 - Python2 teve sua ultima versão em 2010, e não evolui mais - em 3 anos vai parar de ser mantida, e se sua base de código estiver grande, você vai ter que portar antes disso.

(E, sim, qualquer script que vá fazer coisa parecida precisa rodar como root. Se for necessário na documentação do `sudo` você pode encontrar formas de outros usuários poderem rodar só o seu programa com privilégios de root).